# Sigmoid function increasing for large values of variable x

Tags: functions, special-functions, exponential-function

I am looking for a function that involves the sigmoid function but for large values of variable $x$ increases. Maybe sth like this, but there is a part missing:
$f(x)= A +B\ \frac{1}{(1+e^{-x})}\ +\ \textbf{?}$

where A,B are constants. Any suggestion?

Comment: If you want it to increase, just multiply the logistic function by something that grows as $x$ grows. Taylor that one to the growth you want (the logistic in itself gets asymptotically 1)

Answer (score 0):

These are functions that "live" between $c$ and $1$. But you can scale them to arbitrary domains. $\Phi$ is the cumulative normal distribution.

$$f_1=\frac{1-c}{\pi}\arctan(a(x-b))+\frac{1+c}{2}$$
$$f_2=(1-c)\Phi(a(x-b))+c$$
$$f_3=\frac{1-c}{2}\frac{a(x-b)}{\sqrt{a^2(x-b)^2+1}}+\frac{1+c}{2}$$

You can also use other cumulative probability functions and rescale them as you wish.